# How I can pass a parameter value in where clause MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have a problem with a mongoDb query, i need to search for a parameter value of any MongoDB field.

I use a function in `$where` clause like:

```
db.response.find(
{
    $where: function() {
        var deepIterate = function  (obj, value) {
            for (var field in obj) {
                if (obj[field] == value){
                    return true;
                }
                var found = false;
                if ( typeof obj[field] === ‘object’) {
                    found = deepIterate(obj[field], value)
                    if (found) { return true; }
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        return deepIterate(this, “Text36")
    }
});
```

The returned response was fine but I don't know how I can pass the value (Text36 in this sample) I want to found like a parameter

can someone help me please ? Thanks

Comment: Can you not just do a `var text = "Text36"` at the very start of your snippet and then write `return deepIterate(this, text)`?

Comment: No text is undefined. I already try this :(

Comment: This does not seem to be a performant approach by any stretch of the imagination. `$where` does not use indexes and you are doing a recursion on all the fields on each record? Have you considered any other way to do what you want? Even if this works with a parameter the performance with large data sets would be pretty bad.

Comment: Using ```db.response.index({ '$**': 'text' });``` and ```db.response.find({$text: {$search: "{{{Text36}}}"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})```solve my problem.